# Creating React component that extends img tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a React component that renders an image from a remote location. I want it to inherit whatever props were passed such as alt, style, className, etc. I don't know what these props are ahead of time.

I managed to write it like this, but I have the issues described below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class BackendImage extends Component {
  render() {
    const remoteImageURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + this.props.backendImagePath;
    return <img {...this.props} src={remoteImageURL} />;
  }
}

export default BackendImage;

BackendImage.propTypes = {
  backendImagePath: PropTypes.string,
};
```

The first issue is that I'm passing the prop backendImagePath down to img that does not recognize it, thus throwing the warning *React does not recognize the `backendImagePath` prop on a DOM element*.

The second issue is another warning that *img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.*

Is my approach the best one? If so, how do I fix these warnings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you're using the spread operator (`{...this.props}`) you're also spreading the `backendImagePath` inside of `img`, which isn't allowed.

Instead you should pick out your own custom props by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operatoren/Destructuring_assignment) the props object, and spreading the other props in a different variable.

```
const { backendImagePath, ...rest } = this.props;

const remoteImageURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + backendImagePath;
return <img {...rest} src={remoteImageURL} />;
```

Comment: That did fix the first warning, but it still complains about a lack of alt tag. That warning probably won't show in production, but is the only way to supress it is it to also extract alt from props and pass it explicitly to the <img>?

Comment: Well, I did what I just suggested and it did work just fine. Here's the final code for the component, feel free to add to your answer if you want. Thanks a lot @Alserda

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class BackendImage extends Component {
  render() {
    const { backendImagePath, alt, ...rest } = this.props;
    const remoteImageURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + backendImagePath;
    return <img {...rest} alt={alt} src={remoteImageURL} />;
  }
}

export default BackendImage;

BackendImage.propTypes = {
  backendImagePath: PropTypes.string,
  alt: PropTypes.string,
};

Comment: The `alt` tag is required when using an image within React. It will always tell you to use one. Your approach is a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above from @Alserda works just fine but does not suppress the warning for the missing alt text in development environment. So here's the final code where I also extract the alt prop and explicitly pass it to the .

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class BackendImage extends Component {
  render() {
    const { backendImagePath, alt, ...rest } = this.props;
    const remoteImageURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + backendImagePath;
    return <img {...rest} alt={alt} src={remoteImageURL} />;
  }
}

export default BackendImage;

BackendImage.propTypes = {
  backendImagePath: PropTypes.string,
  alt: PropTypes.string,
};
```